# Best mongodb collections design for a sms api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developping an sms api with node js and mongoose but I am pretty new to mongodb so I would like to ask you what is the best database design for my problem. My api consist of a http interface that the client will use to send sms. So the client will have a user account in the database and a limited number of sms per hour per month etc. So each time the client try to send an sms a calculation will be made with the date and time of all the client previous sms in order to define if he is authorize to send a new sms. So the different collection design that I can think about are:

- Use an array in the user collection that will contain every sms objects for the particular user. Something like that in the schema 
  sms_sent: [{address: 'XXXXX', sent_date: '2017-05-05 00:01:33'}]. 
  With a collection like that the calculation will be easy and quick but when I would like to do a global reporting, for example get the number of sms sent by all the users the last hour, I think it could be very slow and hard.
- Use a distinct sms collection that will store the sms datas and the user Id of the user who sent the sms. In this case won't the calculation of the number of sms sent by a particular user each time he tries to send sms won't be critical?
- Use a distinct sms collection and only store the ObjectId of the sms sent by the user in the user collection ( sms_sent: [ ObjectId('XXXX'), ObjectId('XXXX')]. I don't know if this solution is efficient.

So I would like to know what is the most efficient solution, the solution that will result in quicker calculation and request. If you have another solution I would like to know it. Thank you in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you keep the sms collection but also keep the sms stats in user collection. Here's how:

```
var smsSchema = new Schema({
    text: {type: String, required: true},
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    sentAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});


var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    sms : {
        subscribed : {type: Boolean, required: true, default: false},
        cellNo : {type: String},
        month : {
            current: {type: Number}, // 01 (Jan)
            limit: {type: Number},   // 2000
            sent: {type: Number},    // 1135
        },
        hour : {
            current: {type: Number},  // e.g. 23 (11 pm)
            limit: {type: Number},    // 200
            sent: {type: Number},     // 157
        }
    },

    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
});
```

Now, whenever sms request from a user comes along:

1. Get the user document
2. Find the current month and match it's same as `user.sms.month.current` (say 01 for Januray)
3. If 2 is true, then check if `user.sms.month.sent` is smaller than the monthly
   limit `user.sms.month.limit` (which you'll have set at the time of
   subscription)
4. If 3 is true, send the sms, create sms document, and increment `user.sms.month.sent` by 1
5. If 3 is false, return some "monthly limit is reached" message
6. If 2 is false, set `user.sms.month.current` to current month, `user.sms.month.sent` to 0 and follow step 4

Apply same steps with `user.sms.hour` fields.

This way you only need a single document of user to identify if his request is authorized. And you're also keeping record of each sms in a separate collection.